# Files specified in include tag in build.xml are not getting added to the jar

Tags: java, ant, build.xml

I want to include config.properties file and all the json files present in resources folder in my jar. But none of the file is getting added to the jar. If I use only one include tag  then those files are getting added to the jar. Please help me add all jsonm and config.properties file to the jar.

```
<!-- Export configuration files to build directory -->
  <copy todir="${output.dir}/configuration">
    <fileset dir="configuration">
      <include name="**/config.properties"/>
      <include name="**/*.json"/>
    </fileset>
  </copy>

  <!-- Put exported configuration files on classpath -->
  <fileset id="extra.jar.files" dir="${output.dir}/configuration">
    <filename name="**/config.properties"/>
    <filename name="**/*.json" />
  </fileset>
```

Comment: Tryy  <fileset dir="configuration"
               includes="**/*.json"/><fileset dir="configuration"
               includes="**/config.properties"/>

Comment: This worked!! thanks @TechFree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<copy todir="${output.dir}/configuration">
    <fileset dir="configuration" includes="*/.json"/>
    <fileset dir="configuration" includes="**/config.properties"/> 
</copy>
```

Refer this [link](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html)